# OpenCV: Resizing an Image

Tags: c, opencv

I seem to miss something but I cannot understand how to resize an image. Here is code:

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IplImage* src = NULL;
    IplImage* dst = NULL;
    src = cvLoadImage("image.tif");
    dst = cvCreateImage(cvSize( src->width / 10, src->height / 10 ), src->depth, src->nChannels );

    resize(src, dst, dst->nSize, 0.1, 0.1, CV_INTER_AREA );

    return 0;
}
```

But this code only results into the compiler error:

```
error C2664: 'cv::resize' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'IplImage *' to 'cv::InputArray'
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong here? I mean how can I create an InputArray from an IplImage?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: I include core.hpp, imgproc.hpp, and highgui.hpp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing up OpenCV C and C++ functions. If you are programming in C++ you should use the [Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) class to store image data. If you are on the other hand using pure C you should use the function [cvResize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#resize) to resize your IplImage.

As you can see in the OpenCV API documentation, there is a C and C++ programming interface for every function. They are essentially doing the same and you can of course use the C functions in C++, but you cannot use C OpenCV structs (like IplImage) with C++ OpenCV functions (like resize()).

[This](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html) introduction describes the basic concepts of the OpenCV C++ API.

Comment: Thanks, I'll introduce myself with the C++ interface. It's just a little weird since I was careful to only include hpp headers.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore. I've created two IplImages in a similar fashion as in the OP, but when I try to use cvResize on them, I get the following runtime error: 

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: [path]/src/matrix.cpp:698: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat